# Routing "member_action" with activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, activeadmin

I made a member action like this :

```
member_action :send_by_email, :method => :get
```

Its supposes to execute Admin::CardsController/send_by_email but it's not, i don't launch the controller action.

My file is cards_controller.rb in app/controllers/admin

```
class Admin::CardsController < ApplicationController
    def send_by_email
       raise "ok"
    end
end
```

When i do rake routes, i got :

```
 send_by_email_admin_card GET        /admin/cards/:id/send_by_email(.:format) admin/cards#send_by_email
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You're overriding your work.

If you define an action in Admin::CardsController you're doing the same as defining it with member_action.

The recommended way is to define Admin Resource Controller actions with member_action instead of digging in their controller.

Answer (score 0):

To debug further, try this:

```
member_action :send_by_email do
  raise "ok" #assuming that works, I use puts statements but whatev.
end
```

I found that I had to put all my 'stuff' in the block within the `app/admin/cards.rb`